# How to call a Gradle task with arguments from another with Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I want to call default `run` task that needs arguments, from another task defined in `build.gradle.kts`. I can call `run` from another task but I do not know how to pass parameters.